# Problemas obteniendo input con .value

Tags: javascript, html

he hecho un formulario en html y javascript, pero el problema viene a la hora de validarlo, pues he creado una funcion validar() que obtiene el texto de los input con .value, el Username funciona perfectamente, pero el password no lo guarda correctamente y en su lugar lo guarda y escribe como undefined (lo escribe para comprobar lo que esta guardando en la constante), y no se el porque. ¿Alguien podría echarme una mano? ¿Es porque esta en un modal? Pero al tratar de sacarlo fuera sigue sin funcionar, así que no se. Y en teoria funciona pues ha sido creado y ejecutado en Google Chorme de otro pc y lo hacia perfectamente, ¿sera que pase mal el código?

¿Cómo se arreglaría o cual seria el error?

```js
function validar(){
  const Username= document.getElementById("Username").value;
  const password= document.getElementById("input-pass").value;
  const x= document.getElementById("demo");
  const passwordreal=`12°22'13.3"N 23°19'20.2"E`;
  x.innerHTML=password.textContent;
if(Username=='e'){
  if(password==passwordreal){
    location.href='https://www.youtube.com/c/OnlineTutorials4Designers/videos'//links de prueba
  }else{
    //location.href='https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCe8xYIQ3m5hzJ0M2fzp9AEw/videos'
  }
}else{
  //location.href='https://www.youtube.com/c/MrBeast6000'
}
}
```

```css
:root{
    --input-color: #80868B;
  --border-color: #DADCE0;
}
body {
    background-image: url("https://64.media.tumblr.com/bd1b0d977b3e43cc5645297d5322662c/tumblr_ndyybljlWc1rvnh7zo1_r1_500.gif");
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 100vh;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
  }
              /* Centrar elemento dentro de main */
  .main {
   position: absolute;
   margin: auto;
   left: 0; right: 0;
   top: 0; bottom: 0;
   width: 1404px/*550px*/;
   height: 658px/*315px*/; line-height: 50px; /* Con «line-height» con el mismo valor numérico de la altura centras horizontalmente el texto */
  
  }
  .video{
      width: 1370px;
   height: 770px;
  }
  .icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    /* top: 0; */
    bottom: 0;
    width: 3vw;
    height: 97vh;
}
.input {
  position: relative;
  background-color: var(--container-color);
  padding: 1.35rem 1.25rem;
  border-radius: .5rem;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  column-gap: .75rem;
}

.input__lock, .input__icon {
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  z-index: 1;
}


.input__lock, .input__password {
  color: var(--white-color);
}

.input__icon {
  color: var(--first-color);
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0.5vw;
  top: 1.5vh;
}

.input__password {
  background: transparent;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 14px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.input__password::placeholder {
  color: var(--white-color);
}

.input__overlay {
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  background-color: var(--white-color);
  position: absolute;
  right: .9rem;
  border-radius: 50%;
  z-index: 0;
  transition: .4s ease-in-out;
}

/* Transition effect */
.overlay-content {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: .5rem;
  right: 0;
}

.overlay-content ~ .input__lock {
  color: var(--container-color);
}

.overlay-content ~ .input__password,
.overlay-content ~ .input__password::placeholder {
  color: var(--text-color);
}
.form{
  width: 360px;
  padding: 4rem 2rem;
  border-radius: 1rem;
}
.form__title{
  font-weight: 400;
  margin-bottom: 3rem;
}
.form__div{
  position: relative;
  height: 48px;
  margin-bottom: 1.5rem;
}
.input__icon {
  color: var(--first-color);
  cursor: pointer;
}
.form__input{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  font-size: var(--normal-font-size);
  border: 1px solid var(--border-color);
  border-radius: .5rem;
  outline: none;
  padding: 1rem;
  background: none;
  z-index: 1;
  color: #f0f0f0;
}
.form__label{
  position: absolute;
  left: 1rem;
  top: 1rem;
  padding: 0 .25rem;
  background-color: var(--bs-dark-rgb);
  color: var(--input-color);
  font-size: var(--normal-font-size);
  transition: .3s;
}
.form__button{
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  padding: .75rem 2rem;
  outline: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: var(--normal-font-size);
  border-radius: .5rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: .3s;
}
.form__button:hover{
  box-shadow: 0 10px 36px rgba(0,0,0,.15);
}

/*Input focus mover arriba label*/
.form__input:focus + .form__label{
  top: -.5rem;
  left: .8rem;
  color: var(--first-color);
  font-size: var(--small-font-size);
  font-weight: 500;
  z-index: 10;
  background-color: #212529;
}

/*Input focus mantener arriba label*/
.form__input:not(:placeholder-shown).form__input:not(:focus)+ .form__label{
  top: -.5rem;
  left: .8rem;
  font-size: var(--small-font-size);
  font-weight: 500;
  z-index: 10;
  background-color: #212529;
}

/*Input focus*/
.form__input:focus{
  border: 1.5px solid var(--first-color);
}

.bx2 {
  font-family: boxicons!important;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-style: normal;
  font-variant: normal;
  /*line-height: 3.5;*/
  text-rendering: auto;
  /*display: inline-block;*/
  text-transform: none;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  position: absolute;
  /* right: 23px; */
  left: 19rem;
  top: 0.80rem;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

.img-content{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  display: block;
}

.img-content:hover{
  cursor: pointer;
}
/*====================================================================================*/

.box2 img {
  object-fit: fill;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        
        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Spectral+SC:400,600" rel="stylesheet">
        <script type="module" src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@5.5.2/dist/ionicons/ionicons.esm.js"></script>
        <script nomodule src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@5.5.2/dist/ionicons/ionicons.js"></script>
        <title>Prueba</title>
        <!--=============== BOXICONS ===============-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/boxicons@latest/css/boxicons.min.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.10.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-7+zCNj/IqJ95wo16oMtfsKbZ9ccEh31eOz1HGyDuCQ6wgnyJNSYdrPa03rtR1zdB" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-QJHtvGhmr9XOIpI6YVutG+2QOK9T+ZnN4kzFN1RtK3zEFEIsxhlmWl5/YESvpZ13" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <div class="icon">
            <a href="#uploads" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#uploads"><ion-icon name="reorder-four-outline" size="large"></ion-icon></a>

        </div>
        <div class="main">
            <iframe class="video" width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/2ykTzIK4xMY" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        </div>
        <!--Modal-->
        <div class="modal fade" id="uploads" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;">
            <div class="modal-dialog bg-dark">
              <div class="modal-content bg-dark">
                <div class="modal-header bg-dark">
                  <h5 class="modal-title bg-dark" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
                  <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                      <div class="card text-white bg-dark mb-3" style="max-width: 80rem;">
                        <h3 style="color:#ffffff" class="card-header"><i class="far fa-image" aria-hidden="true"></i>Login</h3>
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <p id="demo"></p>
                          <form id="Formulario" action="javascript:void(0);" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" autocomplete="off">
                              <br>
                              <div class="form__div">
                                <input id="Username" type="text" class="form__input" placeholder=" " autofocus name="Email">
                                <label for="" class="form__label">Username</label>
                              </div>
            
                            <div class="form__div">
                                <div class="input__overlay" id="input-overlay"></div>
                                <input type="password" placeholder=" " class="form__input" id="input-pass" name="Password">
                                <label for="" class="form__label">Password</label>
                                <i class='bx bx-hide input__icon' id="input-icon"></i>
                            </div>
                              <br>
                            <script>
                                /*=============== SHOW / HIDDEN INPUT ===============*/
const showHiddenInput = (inputOverlay, inputPass, inputIcon) =>{
    const overlay = document.getElementById(inputOverlay),
          input = document.getElementById(inputPass),
          iconEye = document.getElementById(inputIcon)
          
    iconEye.addEventListener('click', () =>{
        // Change password to text
        if(input.type === 'password'){
            // Switch to text
            input.type = 'text'

            // Change icon
            iconEye.classList.add('bx-show')
        }else{
            // Change to password
            input.type = 'password'

            // Remove icon
            iconEye.classList.remove('bx-show')
        }

        // Toggle the overlay
        overlay.classList.toggle('overlay-content')
    })
}

showHiddenInput('input-overlay','input-pass','input-icon')
                            </script>
                              <br>
                              <div class="form-group">
                                  <button type="submit" onclick="validar()" class="btn btn-outline-light">
                                      <i class="fa fa-upload" aria-hidden="true"></i>Subir Imagen
                                  </button>
                                  
                              </div>
                          </form>
                      </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!--Fin Modal-->
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Con algo más trivial si que funciona, pero necesito que sean las coordenadas, porque es para un juego (escape room online) para unos amigos así que no me preocupa que se pueda sacar facilmente. Pero gracias @masterguru

Comment: Pues asegúrate que el símbolo `°` lo puedan escribir, porque me parece que ahí tienes el problema... sácalo de la password y prueba de nuevo a ver si es ese

Comment: Vale, @masterguru, es eso lo que falla, pero como podría ponerlo entonces, es porque el html no esta configurado para ningún  idioma? Si es posible, si no pues nada...

Comment: Fíjate si en tu head tienes un <meta charset> y que pone allí

Comment: @masterguru entonces con <meta charset="ANSI"> deberia funcionar, porque en el ANSI se incluye el º o con <meta charset="UTF-8"> también valdría? He iría al principio del <head> ¿no? Porque no cuento con uno en le head

Comment: Yo usaría el UTF-8, sino puedes tener problemas con los caracteres normales de tu página... el otro nunca lo he visto aplicado en ninguna parte. Aún así no estoy seguro al 100% que sea la solución, pero quizás con eso ya vale. Y sí, ponlo por encima de los scripts y los links, por si acaso.

Comment: @materguru si que funciono el charset UTF-8. Gracias

Comment: Perfecto, gracias por responder. Acabo de agregar una respuesta. Si la ves bien te ruego la aceptes para que la pregunta no quede pendiente para siempre. En este [enlace](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/428/263200) te explican como se aceptan las respuestas y el porque es importante aceptarlas en [este otro](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). Veo que tambien necesitas hacer el [tour] para aprender mejor como funciona este sitio y así poder colaborar mejor con la comunidad. Saludos!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema venia dado por **no establecer una página de códigos en la cabecera del HTML** que uniformara la entrada de caracteres en todos los navegadores.

Como tenía una contraseña como esta:

```
const passwordreal=`12°22'13.3"N 23°19'20.2"E`;
```

el caracter especial `°` **no era reconocido del mismo modo** en todos los navegadores al carecer de una definición previa de la página de códigos que se debia utilizar en el HTML, y cada uno lo podía interpretar de forma distinta por distintos motivos.

La **solución** ha sido establecerla mediante el elemento `<meta charset>` de este modo:

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
```

que es la **misma codificación de página de códigos que está usando en su script**, por lo tanto los navegadores **se ven forzados a usarla** cuando reciben las entradas desde el teclado, y de este modo tanto dicha entrada como el dato guardado en el archivo de javascript o HTML con codificación UTF-8 coinciden siempre y pueden usarse sin problemas.